# Guice JpaRepositoryModule with multiple Persistence Units

Tags: jpa, guice, persistence.xml, guice-persist

I've declared my 2 PUs on persistence.xml as below:

```
<persistence-unit name="myJpaUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <!-- JPA entities must be registered here -->
    <class>MyUserClass</class>...

<persistence-unit name="anotherJpaUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <!-- JPA entities must be registered here -->
    <class>MyAnotherClass</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"></property>...
```

Configured JpaPersistenceModule as below:

```
new IBSJpaRepositoryModule("myJpaUnit", "anotherJpaUnit")
```

Binded the repository classes:

```
protected void bindRepositories(RepositoryBinder binder) {
    binder.bind(UserRepository.class).to("myJpaUnit");

    binder.bind(TableauUserRepository.class).to("anotherJpaUnit");
}
```

Repository classes are annotated with @Transacional declaring wich PU it is:

```
@Transactional(value = "myJpaUnit")
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String>, EntityManagerProvider {

}

@Transactional(value = "anotherJpaUnit", readOnly = true)
public interface TableauUserRepository extends JpaRepository<TableauUser, Integer> {

}
```

I have only one Entity mapped on "anotherJpaUnit", declared this way:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="anotherJpaUnit")
@Entity(name = "_user")
@Data
public class TableauUser {
    @Id
    private int id;
    @Column(length = 255)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "url_namespace", length = 255)
    private String urlNamespace;
    @Column(length = 255)
    private String status;
}
```

But when I start my application, Guice initialization throws errors:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: myJpaUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:287)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
... 38 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: _user
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1265)
```

The table "_user" only exists on "anotherJpaUnit", why it tries to bind with "MyJpaUnit"? I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Anyone has an example of JpaRepositoryModule with multiple PU working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem. We must explicit at persistence.xml to consider only classes declared on it. Not scan all @Entity. See the correct persistence.xml declaration and note the  tag.

```
<persistence-unit name="tableauJpaUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <!-- JPA entities must be registered here -->
    <class>MyUserClass</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>......
```